# Group of exponent $2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

When I have a group $G$ of exponent $2$ and I know that all elements in $G-\{e\}$ are conjugated, is it right that $G$ is of order $2$?

**My try:** For $g,h \in G - \{e\}$ the conjugation assumption implies $$ga=ah$$ but since $\exp G=2$ then $G$ is abelian and therefore $$ga=ha$$

It follows that $g=h$.

Comment: It is correct. In an Abelian group, "conjugate" is another name for "equal" so the property easily follows from the fact that exponent-2 groups are Abelian.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $x, y \in G$. Then $yx = y^{-1}x^{-1}= (xy)^{-1} = xy$ by the hypothesis. Hence $G$ having an exponent 2 implies that $G$ is abelian.

Choose $a, b \ G\backslash\{1 \}$.

Then there exists a $g$ such that $b = gag^{-1}$.

Then $h = ba^{-1} = gag^{-1}a^{-1} = 1$ since $G$ is abelian.
It follows that $a = b$ and we have the result as it was promised.