# How to prove a semigroup with properties $x^3=x$ and $x^2y^2=y^2x^2$ is commutative

Tags: semigroups

> If $S$ is a semigroup such that $$(\forall x,y\in S)\quad x^3=x\quad\text{and}\quad x^2y^2=y^2x^2,$$prove that
> $$(\forall x,y\in S)\quad xy=yx.$$

All I did is prove $$x^2y^2=(x^2y^2)^2\quad\text{and}\quad xy^2x=(xy^2x)^2.$$

- Proof of $x^2y^2=(x^2y^2)^2$:

From $x^2y^2=y^2x^2,$ we deduce $x^2x^2y^2y^2=x^2y^2x^2y^2=(x^2y^2)^2.$

Taking into account $x^4=x^2,$ the result follows.

- Proof of $xy^2x=(xy^2x)^2$:

$xy=x^3y^3=xx^2y^2y=xy^2x^2y=(xy^2x)(xy)$ hence $xyyx=(xy^2x)(xy)(yx) =(xy^2x) ^2,$ which was the claim.

Comment: I think you already gave "some context". What @C-RAM meant is perhaps your question would be better "received" if you present at least a proof of the 2 properties you say you already got. You could also tell where this problem comes from, why you think it is true.

Comment: Do we agree that a semigroup operation is only associative ? (no neutral element.)

Comment: (same question as Anne Bauval) What is the origin of this exercise ?

Comment: I find your question interesting and I suspect the result is false, but constructing a counterexample is uneasy. If you edit your question to improve it (following the advices in the blue box above), it can be reopened.

Comment: You claim "$xy^2x=(yx^2y)^2,yx^2y=(xy^2x)^2$" but what you present is a proof of $xy^2x=(xy^2x)^2.$ I took the liberty of correcting. Hopefully I am not mistaken.

Comment: What about $x=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $y=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ ? Both $x^2=y^2=I$ so fulfil the criteria, but do not commute. It should work for any non commutative involutions.

Comment: @zwim the semigroup generated by your two involutions $x,y$ is a nonabelian group hence it cannot satisfy $\forall z\quad z^3=z.$ For instance, $(xy)^3=-(xy)\ne xy.$

Comment: Ah, yes we have only $(xy)^4=I$. I spoke too fast... I let the comment, it might serve as a warning.

Comment: @AnneBauval This problem is given by my teacher from a book, the problem received in turn from someone, but I don't know the name of the book.

Comment: I wish I could give more information.

Comment: @JeanMarie I "agree that a semigroup operation is only associative (no neutral element)" but this theorem about semigroups is equivalent to its restriction to monoids (by adjunction of an identity element).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a structural proof, which follows from an old result of Clifford [1]. There is certainly a direct proof only using the given identities, but it might be more artificial.

Let $S$ be a semigroup satisfying the two identities
\begin{align}
  (1) \quad &x^3 = x \\
  (2) \quad &x^2y^2 = y^2x^2
\end{align}
First observe that, for every $x \in S$, $x^2$ is idempotent. Indeed,
$$
x^2x^2 = x^3x = xx = x^2.
$$
It follows by (2) that idempotents commute in $S$. On the other hand, (1) shows that $S$ is a [completely regular semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_regular_semigroup), that is, every element of $S$ belongs to some subgroup of $S$. Indeed, every element $x$ belongs to the subgroup $H(x) = \{x, x^2\}$ of $S$.
It follows that $S$ is the union of these subgroups and every [$\mathcal{H}$-class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_relations) of $S$ is a (maximal) subgroup of $S$. Moreover, (1) shows that these maximal groups have exponent $2$ and hence are commutative (see for instance [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1650606) for a proof).

The structure of completely regular semigroups with commuting idempotents is described in Theorem 3 of [1]. It says that $S$ is a *semilattice of groups*, in the following sense. The idempotents of $S$ form a semilattice $E$ and $S$ is the disjoint union of groups $G_e$, $e \in E$. If $e > f$, there is a morphism $\varphi_{e,f}:G_e \to G_f$ such that, if $e > f > k$, then $\varphi_{f,k} \circ \varphi_{e,f} = \varphi_{e,k}$. Now, the product on $S$ is defined as follows. If $g_e \in G_e$ and $h_f \in G_f$ are two elements of $S$ and if $k = ef$, then the product $g_eh_f$ is in $G_k$ and is computed as follows:
$$
  g_eh_f = \varphi_{e,k}(g_e) \varphi_{f,k}(h_f)
$$
Now, in your case, since $ef = fe$ and since $G_k$ is a commutative group,
this product is commutative.

[1] A. H. Clifford, [Semigroups admitting relative inverses](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1968781.pdf), *Ann. of Math.* (2) **42** (1941), 1037--1049.