# Proving a semigroup is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, semigroups

> Let $M$ be a set with an internal binary operation, denoted $\cdot$. Knowing that $(M, \cdot)$ is a semigroup and if there exists a natural number $n$ such that $x^ny^n=yx$, $\forall (x, y) \in M^2$, prove that $(M, \cdot)$ is a commutative semigroup.

My approach was to try using the fact that $xy=y^nx^n$ and to raise $yx$ to the power of $n$ and $(yx)^n=y(xy)^{n-1}x=y^{n+1}(x^ny^n)^{n-2}x^{n+1}=y^{n+1}(yx)^{n-2}x^{n+1}$ and we have a recurrence formula: $(yx)^n=a_n=y^{n+1}a_{n-2}x^{n+1}$ where $a_2=(yx)^2, a_1=yx$. We can't have $a_0$, because we do not have an identity element. The same recurrence relation can be deduced for $(xy)^n=b_n=x^{n+1}b_{n-2}y^{n+1}$, but I feel that this leads to nowhere. How could I draw a conclusion, knowing that there could not exist an identity element.

Comment: Maybe (just a guess) you have to show that $n\neq1$ leads to difficulties. E.g. when $n\neq 1$ the statement gives that $x^nx^n=x^2$ for all $x\in M$, which leads to a very strange semigroup I think.

Comment: Some similarity with the recent question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4634054/305862). Do you belong to the same group ?

Comment: Solution [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1930790p13260003) (found using [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search) formula searching tool.)